# Can I have more than one consistency model for documentDb collection?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a web application which talks to microservices hosted in service fabric cluster (which means a given service can be hosted on more than one node). The microservices talk to documentDb collections. Lets say we have one service talks to a distinct collection. We have batch processing which also leverage some of these microservices.

We would like to follow strong consistency model for UI related requests in our microservices so that users are not surprised by the results. Since non-sql database performs best with eventual consistency, we would like to use eventual consistency for batch processing.

1. Is it possible to choose eventual consistency at collection/account level in documentDb?
2. With (1), can I also choose strong consistency for my UI operations (from microservices)?

We are only looking for a condition where both (1) and (2) are true at the same time.

If both (1) and (2) are possible at the same time, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Raghu 
Yes., It is already supported.

You can relax consistency at individual request level and use Strong for UI(default).

For setting the consistency at request level - kindly see - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.consistencylevel.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions.ConsistencyLevel

Comment: This appears to be exact opposite of what I am asking. Does this mean we first have to set the default consistency to Strong and use Eventual Consistency in individual operations? Or can I first set the default consistency to Eventual Consistency and use Strong consistency in individual operations? Or both options are possible?

Comment: Yes - first set the default consistency to Strong and use Eventual Consistency in individual operations. Consistency applies to the Read operations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-consistency-levels , write operations are always quorum committed  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-distribute-data-globally - "The latency guarantees for writes include durable majority quorum commits within the local datacenter".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is not possible to have weaker consistency model at the default level and have stronger consistency at the client level. See: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/7056677-allow-clients-to-specify-a-stronger-consistency-le

Comment: That's generally true, but you can alway package a particular operation into a stored procedure and get full ACID transaction consistency.

Comment: I do not follow your statement. Could you please elaborate on how a stored procedure can achieve a high level of consistency (say Strong) when the default level is set to, say, Eventual Consistency?

Comment: Note this only applies to data in the same partition but all of the operations including any combination of reads and writes that occur within a single execution of a SPROC will either all work or all fail.